# How can I find a list of stored procedure using specified column in where clause / condition?

Tags: sql-server

I have more than 1000 Stored Procedures in our database and wanted to find which procedure using Table.Column in where clause / condition. (If Table.column used in only select list then that procedure is not useful for me)

Comment: If the actual number of procedures referencing a column is limited (as opposed to the total number of procedures overall), you can use `sys.sql_expression_dependencies` to find them and then manually filter those that are referencing it in the `WHERE` clause. If the number is too large for this or it has to be automatable, extract the procedure definitions with `sys.sql_modules` or a DACPAC and then use `TSqlParser` to visit the `WHERE` clauses. This assumes a working knowledge of .NET.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be 100% what you want, but as a very quick way to check what procedures list the Table/Column after the WHERE you could easily do something like this

```
select objecT_name(id)as ProcedureName,* from syscomments where text like '%where%mycolumn%'
```